A psychotic young boy obsessed with his "mother"
This movie is about a 13-16 year old white psychotic boy who wants a new mother (through adoption). He killed a girl simulating a "stair" incident (in which the girl uses the stairs for exiting from her house to meet her boyfriend discreetly).
He also tried to kill a man (probably a mechanic) by setting up a gas explosion, but the man survives and the boy gets arrested at the end of the movie.
The boy made all the kills for the love of his "mother", wanting her all for himself.
Release year: 1990-94
Format: probably a TV movie
Country: USA
Other Info: none

Somewhat reminiscent of Mikey from 1992, but some details are a bit off.

No,is not MIkey,is a little older 13-16 years,Bonsall was 12yo when play Mikey in 1992

Ah, you're not after Mikey but rather the similar The Paperboy from 1994.

A homicidal twelve-year-old paperboy becomes obsessed with a woman and her daughter next-door, and he'll do anything to make his fantasy of the "perfect family" come alive.

He tampers with the ladder-like antenna that the daughter uses to sneak out and meet her boyfriend, and she falls and gets injured. He later tries to kill the boyfriend who's a mechanic and sets him on fire, but the boyriend survives. You can see both scenes in the trailer:



